# expect for ssh passwordless

Tags: bash, ssh, expect

i have a file that has ip addresses, locations of files and passwords. I cannot use ssh key authentification, that's why i'm limited to use expect inside a bash script. the file contain the information as follow, seperated by spaces:

ip location password

ip location password

etc

my script is :

```
 VAR=$(expect -c "
        set fid [open "file.conf" w]
        set content [read $fid]
        close $fid
        set records [split $content "\n"]
        foreach rec $records {
        set fields [split $rec]
        lassign $fields\ ip location password
        puts "$ip"
        puts "$location"
        puts "$password"}
        spawn ssh $ip tail -f $location > /home/log_$ip 2>/dev/null &
        expect {
                ".*Are.*.*yes.*no.*" { send "yes\n" }
                "*?assword:*" { send "$password\r" }
           }
    ")
```

echo "$VAR"

when i run the script, it gives me this error :

wrong # args: should be "read channelId ?numChars?" or "read ?-nonewline? channelId"
    while executing
"read "
    invoked from within
"set content [read ]"

Comment: can somebody please help me make tail -f run in the background

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the expect body in single quotes, so the expect variables are not expanded by the shell before expect starts to execute.

Also, if you hit the "are...yes...no" prompt, then you need to use `exp_continue` so you can keep expecting the password prompt.

**DON'T OPEN THE CONF FILE WITH "w"** -- you will destroy the file contents. You are reading from it, so open it for reading

```
VAR=$(expect -c '
    set fid [open "file.conf" r]
    while {[gets $fid line] != -1} {
        lassign [split $line] ip location password
        puts "$ip"
        puts "$location"
        puts "$password"
        spawn ssh $ip tail -n 20 $location > /home/log_$ip 2>/dev/null &
        expect {
            -re "Are.*yes.*no" { send "yes\r"; exp_continue }
            -gl "*?assword:*" { send "$password\r" }
        }
    }
')
```

I'm not sure if this will work when you redirect spawn output: I'm worried that expect will the have nothing to work with. If this doesn't work, remove "`> /home/log_$ip 2>/dev/null &`" or use

```
spawn ssh $ip tail -n 20 $location 2>/dev/null | tee /home/log_$ip
```

---

For backgrounding, you probably have to do something like this (untested)

```
expect -c '...' > /home/log_$ip 2>&1 &
expect_pid=$!

# ...

# later
wait $expect_pid
VAR=$(< /home/log_$ip)
do something with "$VAR"
```

Comment: this looks good, i am actually using tail -f and i want it to run in the background so i added & to your line spawn ssh $ip tail -f $location 2>/dev/null | tee /home/log_$ip but it is not working.

Comment: your answer is very useful if only i could run the command in the background.

Comment: You could launch the whole expect program in the background, but then $VAR will not capture anything.

Comment: i need $VAR, because i am running expect from a bash script.

Comment: If you launch it in the background, you have to redirect to a file because you won't be able to capture the output in a variable. Then you will have to wait for the background process to complete before you can read the file.

Comment: Is there a way to ask the user to input the password once, as opposed to take the password from the file?